# How do I use a cell as input to a function?

Tags: excel

I am using the INDEX function in Excel 2010 and I want to be able to give the input off which sheet to look in in a cell:

instead of INDEX('sheet1',,) I want INDEX(A1,,) and A1 contains sheet1.

Can I do this, how?

Regards,
Klas

Comment: maybe [INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)? See my [**answer to the similar question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053454/excel-link-to-another-sheet-in-same-workbook/21053548#21053548)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what the `INDIRECT` function is made for.  Here are the [official details](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx).

If A1 has value SHEET1, your formula would be something like:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1&"!C1:C200"),6)
```

where

- `A1&"!C1:C200"` resolves to "Sheet1!C1:C200" which is the range you want to use Index on.  You'll have to replace C1:C200 with whatever the target range on sheet1 is
- Just a note of caution, INDIRECT is a 'volatile' function meaning it recalculates every time a change is made anywhere in the workbook.  For that reason, it can make your workbook s - l - o - w if you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

Wghat you are looking for is the [INDIRECT Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)  that will take a text value (the value in a cell) and convert that to a Range reference.

Try the following:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1),,)
```